# How map reduce is being performed in this HiveQL query?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql, hadoop-partitioning

```
FROM (
  FROM pv_users
  SELECT TRANSFORM(pv_users.userid, pv_users.date)
  USING 'python mapper.py'
  AS dt, uid
  CLUSTER BY dt) map_output
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE pv_users_reduced
SELECT TRANSFORM map_output.dt, map_output.uid
  USING 'python reducer.py'
  AS date, count;
```

How map reduce is working in this query and what is the significance of `"CLUSTER BY"` in this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each mapper will read file splits, do something with their splits (for example pre-aggregation like distinct) and produce dt, uid grouped and sorted by dt, so different `dt` will be put in different files which will be consumed by reducers on the next step.

Reducers will read files prepared by mappers, so records with the same `dt` will be read by the same reducer because records were distributed by dt and sorted on mapper.
Reducer will merge partial results(files from mappers) and do some `count` aggregation. If some `dt` were in the same file, records are sorted, it reduces the amount of work to be done on reducer.

`cluster by dt` = `distribute by dt sort by dt`

Without `cluster by`, two reducers may receive same dt, this will make impossible to perform count correctly because reducers do not know about each other and do not share data between them, same `dt` will be counted partially on different reducers, final result will contain multiple records with the same `dt`